# How to enter text into a web page form field with WxWebView

Tags: c++, webview, wxwidgets, autofill

I'm using wxWebView (with chromium) to load a web page.

This page contains a number of form fields, and I'd like to be able to automatically fill some of those fields in the same way as a normal browser can.

How can I do this with wxWebView as I can't see any methods for interacting with a web page after it has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this in the end.

wxWebView has a "RunScript" method, which can run arbitrary javascript. With this, you can do pretty much anything you'd need.